# Vivekachudamani Of Adi Sankaracharya

Tags: philosophy, translation-request, vedanta, adi-shankaracharya, advaita

I have the "Vivekachudamani" of Adi Sankaracharya in Sanskrit language with word-by-word meaning in Hindi but still I am finding very difficult to understand it.

- Is there any Online site (for Hard copy/ soft copy) available in English/Hindi translation or commentaries of "Vivekachudamani" in order to understand it's Adhyatmik rahashya? or
- Does any YouTube link available on this(for easy reference)?

As per one of spiritual enlightened person said that, "Vivekachudamani (famous Sanskrit poem) is one of most perfect book to find a perfect Guru (By knowing his qualities) and become a prominent disciple and finally leads to (those who want/aspirant for) MOKSHA.

> The Vivekachudamani describes developing Viveka—the human faculty of discrimination— as the central task in the spiritual life and calls it the crown jewel among the essentials for Moksha. The title Vivekachudamani translates to **Crest Jewel of Discrimination**. It has the form of dialogue between the master and the disciple, where the master explains to the disciple the nature of the Atman and the ways to research and know the Atman. The book takes the disciple on a step by step instructions to reach Brahman. It then expounds the significance of Self Realisation, ways to reach it, and the characteristics of a Guru. It teaches the disciple the ways to attain Self-realization, methods of meditation (dhyana) and introspection of the Atman.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivekachudamani)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This website](http://www.universaltheosophy.com/sacred-texts/crest-jewel-of-wisdom/) provides three translations of the Vivekachudamani.  And [here](http://www.realization.org/down/sankara.vivekachudamani.chaitanya.pdf) is one more translation, in PDF format.

As far as commentaries go, you can watch [this](https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkpR1TQMei4Xo6N56szmxsAhH3KL9-koS) series of lectures on YouTube, or you can listen to [this](http://hinduonline.co/AudioLibrary/Discources/CommentaryonVivekachudamaniParamarthananda.html) audio commentary by Swami Paramarthananda.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend the translation included in this book:

http://www.universaltheosophy.com/kshetra-books/#vedanta

It also includes other works of Sankaracharya (Atma Bodha, Tattva Bodha, Atmanatma-viveka, etc.), along with articles on the Vedanta Philosophy. Really helps to get a grasp on the main concepts of Advaita Vedanta.

Answer (score 1):

You should purchase this book-SRI SAMKARA'S VIVEKACUDAMANI WITH AN ENGLISH TRANSLATION OF THE SANSKRIT COMMENTARY OF SRI CHANDRASEKHARA BHARATI OF SRINGERI (English)- http://www.flipkart.com/sri-samkara-s-vivekacudamani-english-translation-sanskrit-commentary-chandrasekhara-bharati-sringeri-english/p/itmdyu5jqvgrr6vf

The book contains english translation of Sanskrit commentary on Vivekachoodamani written by late Jagadguru Sri Chandrashekara Bharati Mahaswami of Sringeri Peetham.